what are $\hat{a}^\dagger_j$ and $\hat{a}_j$ in quantum duopoly game in the paper Continuous-Variable Quantum Games
$$
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \rvert #1 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left \langle #1 \middle \rvert #2 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\braxket}[3]{\left \langle #1 \middle \rvert #2 \middle \rvert #3 \right \rangle}
$$
I am confused by the quantum operators in quantum duopoly game in the paper Continuous-Variable Quantum Games written by Li-Du-Massar.

Background:

In the paper, the oberservable (i.e. position operator) is given by
$$\hat{X}_j=(\hat{a}_j^\dagger+\hat{a}_j)/\sqrt{2} \tag{1}$$, and the momentum operator is given by
$$\hat{P}_j=i(\hat{a}_j^\dagger-\hat{a}_j)/\sqrt{2} \tag{2}$$,
where $\hat{a}_j^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}_j$ denote the creation and annihilation operator respectively.
The strategy $\hat{D}_j(x_j)$ of player $j$ is that $$\hat{D}_j(x_j)=\text{exp}(-ix_j\hat{P}_j),x_j\in[0,\infty),j=1,2  \tag{3}$$.
The entangling operation is given by
$$\hat{J}(\gamma)=\text{exp}(-\gamma(\hat{a}_1^\dagger\hat{a}_2^\dagger-\hat{a}_1\hat{a}_2)) \tag{4}$$.
The final ouput of the game is given by
$$\ket{\psi_f}=\hat{J}^\dagger(\gamma)(\hat{D}_1(x_1) \otimes\hat{D}_2(x_2))\hat{J}(\gamma)\ket{\psi_{in}} \tag{5}$$
where the input of the game $\ket{\psi_{in}}$ is given by $\ket{\psi_{in}}=\ket{00}$.
So the final measurement gives the respective quantities of the two firms $q_j$: $$q_j=\braxket{\psi_f}{\hat{X}_j}{\psi_f} \tag{6}$$

My Question

I don't know about what $\hat{a}^\dagger_j$ and $\hat{a}_j$ are. The reason why I am confused is that if $\hat{a}^\dagger_j$ or $\hat{a}_j$ is a $2 \times 2$ operator, then $\hat{X}_j$ and $\hat{P}_j$ are $2 \times 2$ operators. It follows that $\hat{D}_j(x_j)$ and $\hat{J}(\gamma)$ are $2 \times 2$ operators. But $\hat{D}_1(x_1) \otimes\hat{D}_2(x_2)$ is $4\times 4$, so the dimension is not matched in the calculation of $\ket{\psi_f}$ in (5).

My Attempt

Then I guess that $\hat{a}_1^\dagger\hat{a}_2^\dagger-\hat{a}_1\hat{a}_2$ in the calculation of $\hat{J}(\gamma)$ omits the kron operator, but it still gives me confusion. If the kron operatorindeed is indeed omitted, the shape of $\ket{\psi_f}$ is  $4\times 1$ but the one of $\hat{X}_j$ is $2 \times 2$, so the dimension is not matched in the calculation of $q_j$ in (6).
I don't know which step is wrong. If anyone could give me any advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Actually, there is an implicit convention that an operator defined on a subsystem only acts as the identity on the other subsystem, such that $\hat{a}_1$ has to be understood as $\hat{a}_1 \otimes \hat{1}_2$ for instance and thus a product of operators behaves as in the following example : $\hat{a}_1^\dagger\hat{a}_2^\dagger|\psi_1\psi_2\rangle = \hat{a}_1^\dagger|\psi_1\rangle \otimes \hat{a}_2^\dagger|\psi_2\rangle$.
In addition, it is to be noted that the paper you mentioned deals with continuous variables, as said in its title, that is why the state space of each subsystem is infinite-dimensional in fact $-$ although this formalism works fine with finite-dimensional spaces too.

Thanks for your answer. After reading your answer, I have three following questions:

Noting the circuit diagram in the paper, I understand that the shape of \hat{D} and \hat{J} must be 22 and 44 respectively. So the shape of creation/annihilation operator is 2*2, the calculation of \hat{J} omits the kron operator, and X_j in (6) should be the tensor product of X_j and I_2 according to your first paragraph. However, I still cannot reproduce the result. May I ask which step I misunderstood?




My understanding of continuous variable is that, 'continuous variable' is reflected in the parameter x_j of strategy D, not the infinite-dimensional state space of each subsystem you mentioned in your second paragraph. Because 'continuous variable' emphasizes that q_j is continuous. So I think that the state space of each subsystem is finite-dimensional.


If you don't mind the trouble, can you provide a specific matrix representation of a, X, P, D, J?


Thank you for your patience and time.

@caaaaaat. 1) The diagram displays two interacting fields, indeed, but each field is represented by a state vector living in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. You seem to mistake the "dimensionality" of the global Hilbert space $-$ meaning that it is split into two subspaces associated to each field through a tensorial product $-$ for the dimensions of the Hilbert space itself as a vector space.

@caaaaaat. 2) The parameters $x_j$ correspond to the eigenvalues of the operator $\hat{X}_j$. Yet, the first paragraph of the second chapter explains that its spectrum is assumed continuous and that it possesses a continuous set of eigenvectors. Consequently, the latter span an (uncountably) infinite-dimensional vector space. Otherwise $\hat{X}_j$ would admit a discrete spectrum made of two eigenvalues only. The same reasoning applies the other operators.

@caaaaaat. 3) Sorry, I can't, because the matrix representation is not suitable in the case of infinite-dimensional vector spaces, obviously. Moreover, the said representation would depend on the chosen basis. Nonetheless, the position operator $\hat{X}$ could be represented as $\hat{X} = \int x|x\rangle\langle x| \mathrm{d}x$ with respect to its eigenbasis for example, while the momentum operator $\hat{P}$ is given by $\hat{P} = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ with respect to to the same basis for instance.
